# letter-spacing is different with same browser, font, size, ect in chrome

Tags: html, css, fonts

I was tasked to rewrite the html and css for a page from scratch, but reach the same visual result. I've found a very strange result while trying to match up letter-spacing on an element between the two pages. The old element is `letter-spacing: 0`, but to match letter-spacing, I had to set new element to `letter-spacing: 0.015em`.

Old

[image]

New

[image]

I don't have a proper image editing software handy to super impose them ontop of each other, but when swapping between tabs (on the same browser), it is clear that the first and last letters are in exactly the same place, with the same font, font-weight, and font-size. Both explicitly declared and computed as `font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif`.

Yet, the letter-spacing is different between on the on different letters. Look at the space between the `e` and the `r` at end of rubber. I've made all things equal in my inspect element, and the change persists. This is only for Chrome. Behavior is different in other browsers that are outside the scope of this question.

I don't really need to match it up, but I'm curious why this behavior exists. Quantum physics perhaps?

Comment: Which browser? Does it happen in other browsers?

Comment: It's in chrome. Actually, in other browsers the first and last letters don't match up, but I expected that. I would expect that chrome would be consistent within itself.

Comment: Try implicitly setting letter-spacing on the elements in question rather than allowing the browser to apply its defaults. You should see more consistency.

Comment: @Korgrue, thanks, but I already have. Actually, I really should have mentioned that the old element is set to `letter-spacing: 0` and the new element is set to `letter-spacing: 0.015em`. I'll update my question.

Comment: Are you saying on exactly the same page but in different browser tabs?

Comment: @Pangloss different html and css, but aiming for the same result

Comment: Have you compared the *computed* tab in the developer tools?

Comment: If the above elements are in different containers, the results might be different from the inherited rules.

Comment: @Pangloss, ah, the line height is computer different. Could that be it?

Comment: Not sure, line height only affects the vertical space not horizontal.

Comment: It [works fine](http://i.imgur.com/Ko18OFe.png?1) for me on Chrome 47. See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/42mvfm7e/).

Comment: share your html/jsfiddle :)

Comment: @Siddharth I would if I could, but because the issue is the HTML and CSS is the same (probably not really, but as far as I can tell) and I'm still seeing an issue, I'm not going to be able to recreate this on JSfiddle. It would just be the same HTML and CSS twice. Sorry that this is so tricky, was hoping someone knew of some browser quirk that can cause this.

Comment: so, time for the obvious question that for some reason hasn't been asked yet: which fonts do both implementations use? If they're provably the same (including version number, not just font name), what are the full CSS property chains for both? (see your dev tools -> computed properties). Do they differ in any way? If so, remove those differences first and see if this still happens. Finally, take the time to make a minimal, reproducible example. Copy the two pages things differ on, strip all the stuff that doesn't matter, put it online (jsbin, link, etc), so potential helpers can investigate.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans they are both explicitly declared and computed as `font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif`. Sounded very hopeful.

Comment: This is a debugging problem, hope doesn't enter into it. Methodology does: reduce your code to only the problem case, make an itemized list of all things that could possibly be wrong, rewrite the list to how for each of those things you could find out, and then test them one by one. Also, information gleaned from debugging should go in your question, so everyone can see the findings, not buried in what is a considerable-length comment thread at this point =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Without the smile face, that would have read very condescending. Will update my answer.

Comment: yeah, hence the smile face, because people forget that there's no intonation on the internet, and comment fields have a character cap, so you're encouraged to be terse, rather than adding all the words that normally defuse sentences.

Answer (score 2):

If you are ultimately unable to fix this bug (say it is browser related) and it is imperative that the letterspacing be spot on, you can always use a kerning library like [LetteringJS](http://letteringjs.com/) to give you letter spacing control down to the individual letter. I used it on a couple projects and did not notice any significant performance hits (apply it only to elements you need finite control of the lettering on)